# How to read response from loadUrl()?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to fetch and display a webpage using WebView, there are chances of page redirection when the webpage is loaded, so is there any option of reading URL's coming as response from first request? I have to perform certain condition checks based on response URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps worked for me:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
       @Override  
         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

           if(url.equals(" abc.com")){

              //do some thing
           }
           else
               //do some other thing

             super.onPageFinished(view, url);

         } 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at shouldOverrideUrlLoading():

```
WebViewClient wvc = new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url) {
                if (!url.startsWith("http://m.youtube.com/")) {
                    // do something
                    return true;
                } else if (url.startsWith("http://m.youtube.com/watch?")) {
                    // do something different
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
```